# ¿Cómo clono un subdirectorio sólo de un repositorio Git?

Tags: git, github

Quiero clonar sólo [una aplicación](https://github.com/plotly/dash-sample-apps/tree/master/apps/dash-oil-and-gas) de un repositorio que contiene toneladas.

Básicamente parece que sólo necesito clonar un subdirectorio sólo de un repositorio Git. Así probé el método de [este hilo](https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/How-can-I-download-a-specific-folder-from-a-GitHub-repo/td-p/88):

```
(venv) (base) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\DashTutorial>mkdir oil_dashboard

(venv) (base) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\DashTutorial>cd oil_dashboard

(venv) (base) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\DashTutorial\oil_dashboard>git init
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/antoi/Documents/Programming/DashTutorial/oil_dashboard/.git/

(venv) (base) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\DashTutorial\oil_dashboard>git config core.sparseCheckout true

(venv) (base) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\DashTutorial\oil_dashboard>cat >> .git/info/sparsecheckout
'cat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

(venv) (base) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\DashTutorial\oil_dashboard>echo >> .git/info/sparsecheckout

(venv) (base) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\DashTutorial\oil_dashboard>vim .git/info/sparsecheckout
'vim' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

(venv) (base) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\DashTutorial\oil_dashboard>notepad .git/info/sparsecheckout

(venv) (base) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\DashTutorial\oil_dashboard>git pull origin master
remote: Enumerating objects: 162, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (162/162), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (27/27), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSffSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 10054
atal: early EOF
atal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Sin embargo, tengo este error fatal. Entonces, ¿cómo puedo clonar este repositorio específico?

En `.git/info/sparsecheckout` tenemos:

```
apps/dash-oil-and-gas/
```

Aqui esta `git remote -v`:

```
(venv) (base) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\DashTutorial\oil_dashboard>git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/plotly/dash-sample-apps (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/plotly/dash-sample-apps (push)
```

Comment: Parece que hubo varios intentos de editar el fichero `.git/info/sparsecheckout`. ¿Puedes pegar el contenido de ese fichero tal y como ha quedado después de las ediciones?

Comment: No lo puedo probar ahora porque estoy detrás de un proxy, pero veo el git init pero no veo el momento en que has definido el remote de ese repositorio antes de hacer el git pull. ¿Has añadido el repositorio previamente haciendo `git remote add origin https://github.com/plotly/dash-sample-apps.git`? En caso de que lo hayas hecho, ¿puedes pegar el resultado de `git remote -v` para ver que tienes ahí?

Comment: @ordago Ninguno problema. He hecho: `git remote add origin -f https://github.com/plotly/dash-sample-apps`

Comment: ¿Puede ser un problema de conectividad en el momento que has ejecutado el pull? Más info sobre el error de RPC que te ha dado aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46232906/git-clone-error-rpc-failed-curl-56-openssl-ssl-read-ssl-error-syscall-errno

Comment: ¿Cómo quedó al final la cosa? ¿Pudiste clonar la carpeta?